# Split series to alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, transformation

Let $a_n$ be sequence of positive numbers.

Is that true that:

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cdot a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}-a_{2n+1} $ converges
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cdot a_n$ diverges to $\pm \infty$ $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}-a_{2n+1} $ diverges to $\pm \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements are true. The key is to go to partial sums. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^na_n,$ $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{2k}-a_{2k+1}).$ Then

$$T_n = a_1 + S_{2n+1}$$

for all $n.$ Suppose $S_n \to S \in \mathbb R.$ Then the same is true for any subsequence of $S_n.$ Hence $S_{2n+1} \to S,$ which implies $T_n \to a_1 + S.$

The proof of the second statement is the same if we use the following simple result: If $x_n \to \pm \infty,$ then the same is true for the sequence $y_n= x_n + c,$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: No,  $\sum (-1)^n$ does not diverge to infinity.

Comment: Oh I miss that it diverges to $\pm\infty$. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

$$S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^na_n=-a_1+a_2-a_3+a_4-a_5+\ldots+(-1)^Na_N$$

that the above series converges means $\;\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}S_N\;$ exists finitely, say equal to $\;S\;$, but now:

$$\Sigma_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N(a_{2n}-a_{2n+1})=(a_2-a_3)+(a_4-a_5)+\ldots+(a_{2N}-a_{2N+1})\implies$$

$$=\Sigma_N=S_{2N}+a_1\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{}S+a_1$$

as parentheses are disposable in finite sums, and this proves both claims as you wrote them.

If in claim (2) it was given that the alternating series diverges (or doesn't converge), then it doesn't follow, for example

$$a_n:=\begin{cases}1-\frac1{n^2}\;,&n\;\text{odd}\\{}\\\;\;\;1,&n\;\text{even}\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$$

diverges since $\;(-1)^na_n\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ , yet $\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N,\;$ :

$$a_{2n}-a_{2n+1}=1-\left(1-\frac1{(2n+1)^2}\right)=\frac1{(2n+1)^2}\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{2n}-a_{2n+1})\,\text{converges}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\Sigma_N = a_1 + S_{2N+1}?$ And for the divergence question, your series doesn't diverge to $\pm \infty.$

Comment: @zhw Thank you. It really doesn't matter with $\;\Sigma_N\;$ as in both cases it has a finite limit, though you're right. As for the divergence question: I know it doesn't diverge to $\;\pm\infty\;$ , what's what I begin from after I show both claims are true as they were written.